# Select cell C where value in column A equals a and value in column B equals b

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 tables, the first one contains an id, and the latest date the person was called and the comment associated with the phone call:

| id | latest call | call comments |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2021 | comments 1 |
| 2 | 1/12/2020 | comments 2 |
| 3 | 1/1/2021 | comments 3 |
| 4 | not contacted |  |

My second table contains all the phone calls:

| id | call date | call comments |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2021 | comments 1 |
| 3 | 1/1/2019 | comments |
| 3 | 1/1/2021 | comments 3 |
| 1 | 1/1/2021 | comments |
| 2 | 1/11/2019 | comments |
| 2 | 1/12/2020 | comments 2 |
| 1 | 10/1/2020 | comments |

The formula I used for latest call is:

```
=IF(MAX(IF(table_2_ids_range=table_1_id_cell, table_2_date_range)) > 0, MAX(IF(table_2_ids_range=table_1_id_cell, table_2_date_range)), "Not contacted")
```

Which returns the latest call date

However, I'm not sure how to get the comment associated with it, I'd like to do somethings like

```
SELECT cell in column "call comments" WHERE cell in column "id" equals VALUE1 and cell in column "call date" equals VALUE2
```

I tried

```
=IF(AND(table_1_id_cell=table_2_id_range,table_1_date_cell=table_2_date_range),table_2_comments_range,"")
```

but it just returned an empty string

Thanks!

Comment: I edited the post to make it more clear

Comment: • Use this for Call Date `=IF(MAX(INDEX(([@id]=Table2[id])*(Table2[call date]),))=0,"Not Contacted",MAX(INDEX(([@id]=Table2[id])*(Table2[call date]),)))` & for Call Comments `=IFERROR(INDEX(Table2[call comments],MATCH(1,([@id]=Table2[id])*([@[latest call]]=Table2[call date]),0)),"")`

Comment: Have you tried the above formula?

Comment: hey thanks for the comment, I ended up adding a helper column, I will post an answer later today

Comment: **[Refer_This](https://imgur.com/gallery/U2qndSk)** this is what I was referring to and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

combine each id and date on second table as second table's record id.
in first table , simply use vlookup  `vlookup(id&date, a:c, 3,0)`